# What is the best alternative for jQuery thickbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

As jQuery thickbox is not maintained anymore (as of [ThickBox 3.1](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)), what is the best alternative for jQuery thickbox currently available under GPL or similar license. Looks [nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) is best available so far, but is there anything better. (nyromodal has some problems in IE 6)

I am looking for a plugin which can handle ajax forms, inline content replacement, images, using hidden elements and ajax call with flexibility using the callback mechanisms..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and lot of quick prototyping, I feel like my old companion [Nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) is the only option left for me, which gives me flexibility of controlling it using its extensive api, I went through other options given by the users and topup and blockui came closer (rest of them are also good, but doesn't meet my needs). But guys, thanks for the help and input.

Answer (score 31):

I always used slimbox, but found out about [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) the other day. It is *awesome* to say the least. It seems that every feature and detail was thought about and executed brilliantly. We just used it at our studio for the first time this week, but it seems really excellent.

It has a ton of options and even callback events. Definitely check it out.

Answer (score 7):

What about (a little modified Version of) ui.dialog? ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ )
I haven't tested it yet, but it seems to work without any problems.

Comment: Can Dialog be used as a thick box? Does it had capability of loading images as slide shows, loading AJAX content and other similar stuff. I used it as a alert and confirm box replacements and had some other simple capabilities, But in my view it can't be used as a thickbox alternative.

Answer (score 6):

How about TopUp?

http://gettopup.com/

or how about SuperBox?

http://www.pierrebertet.net/projects/jquery_superbox/

Comment: Topup is new to me and looks pretty good. But it doesn't seem to have all the flexibility with the sizing and callbacks. But I will definitely take a look at that

Comment: Please don't put two answers in an answer - answer the question twice. People should be able to vote for one or the other option. It also means more rep for you :-)

Answer (score 4):

All of them:
http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Flowplayer overlay http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html, this is one of the nicest ones I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

We've used BlockUI to great effect:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

Its from the same author as the the forms plugin, amongst others, so should be pretty solid!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI Dialog will work, but you will have to learn other jQuery and jQuery UI components (Ajax, tab strips and 3rd party image viewer plugins).

I like the Jquery approach which will allow you build on a consistent framework,
as opposed to downloading random and maybe not very compatible application-specific widgets.

Comment: WOW!! The example looks pretty good, but it seems you have you use lot of other UI plugins and others to make it work... I will definitely take a look into this, thanks.

Comment: Jquery UI is like a buffet. Just add the ingredients you want.

Start with core.js and all.css, then add your additional js for features if needed.

Want tabs capability? add tabs.js. Need sortable or resizeable? Then add sortable.js or resizeable.js.