# jQuery Modal Dialog without jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I was wondering how to implement a modal dialog with background overlay 
with jQuery without using the jqueryUI plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bunch of jQuery plugins that will handle modal windows for you.  Personally, I've used [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) with great success.

You could always bake your own relatively easily, but popular plugins will often obfuscate the issues with cross-browser positioning, and offer you additional flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Check this related post by me on SO, [Thickbox alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050174/what-is-the-best-alternative-for-jquery-thickbox). Most people liked colorbox, but I personally liked Nyromodal. Check it out.