# How to detect specific element in jQuery event propagation

Tags: jquery, events, live, stoppropagation

I've a notifications window (absolutely positioned div) and I want it to close when clicking everything outside that window.

I tried:

```
<div id="#notifWindow">
    <div id="notifs">Notifications...</div>
    <a class="ajax" data-bla="blabla">Click for ajax</a>
</div>

$(document).on(function(event){
    // If clicking over child elements stopPropagation() else window is closed.
    if ($(this).closest('#notifWindow').length) event.stopPropagation();
    else $('#notifWindow').hide();
})

// Just for your information

$(document).on('click', 'a.ajax', function(event){
    // If I use onclick=event.stopPropagation() in #notifWindow this ajax fails
})
```

Here, $(this) is not the element which throws the event, but the document.

Thank you for your time.

**SOLUTION**

http://jsfiddle.net/8CyQU/

```
// Every .ajax inside #notifWindow (dinamically ajax generated) is executed.
$('#notifWindow').on('click', '.ajax', function(event) {
    alert('This ajax is executed!');
});

// If clicking everywhere inside #notifWindow the propagation of 'click' is stopped
$('#notifWindow').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

$(document).on('click', '#open', function(event){
    $('#notifWindow').slideDown();
    event.stopInmediatePropagation(); // It avoid other click events for (document).
});

// Hides the window clicking everywhere
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
    $('#notifWindow').hide();
});
```

Thank you all :-)

Comment: I don't think this will work. Calling `stopPropagation` when it has reached `document` is too late.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a parent div to #notifWindow.  Place it on top of the rest of the page and under #notifWindow.  Bind your click event to this parent element and when it's clicked, remove #notifWindow and the parent.

You could even add some style elements to this parent div so it's translucent, slightly obscuring the rest of the page.  This is a good visual signal to the user that the notifWindow is important, and also gives the hint that clicking off of the "window" will close it.

Comment: It could be an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `on` isn't hooking any event. Separate from that, you'll want to look at `event.target`. So::

```
$(document).on("click", function(event){
   if ($(event.target).closest("#notifWindow")[0]) {
       // Click on the notify window
   }
   else {
       // Click elsewhere, close the notify window
   }
});
```

That said, the *usual* way to create a modal window is to put an absolutely-positioned `iframe` that's the size of the viewport under the `div`, and capture clicks there. That way, your modal appears above form controls and such in IE, and of course it provides a handy target for clicks. Do a web search on "`iframe` shim" for examples (or [here's a very basic example here on SO I wrote for another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868514/157247)).

Comment: Thank you for event.target, this solves the problem for doing it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/2g6Qs/1/

Use e.stopImmediatePropagation() : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Hope this helps, `:)`

**code**

```
$('.parent').delegate('.child','click',function(e){
    alert('child click');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('.parent').delegate('a.ajax','click',function(e){
    alert('anchor ajax click');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('.parent').bind('click',function(e){
    alert('parent click');
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="parent" id="notifWindow">parent
    <div class="child" id="notifs">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <a class="ajax" data-bla="blabla">Click for ajax</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to understand stopImmediatePropagation();