# Window.open() as modal popup behaviour

Tags: javascript, asp.net

As `window.showmodaldialog` is depreciated in chrome, So I am using window.open() instead. But the problem is that after opening Child window I want my parent window to be disabled and if I click on Parent window it should focus on child window.

I tried with some body attributes like `onmouseover`, `onclick` events it is working to some extent but if there is any button on parent and if I click its respective event is getting invoked.

For now I am disabling the parent window events as below when I am opening Child window.

```
$('body').css({ 'opacity': 0.3, 'pointer-events': 'none' })
```

and after closing child window to resume

```
 $('body').css({ 'opacity': 1, 'pointer-events': 'auto' });
```

Now my question is when I click on Parent window, how can I focus on child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are roughly three parts to this:

1. When you open the child window, put a full-page `iframe` on top of the parent window. [This answer has an explanation and example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4868514/157247) (using jQuery; I note you're using jQuery in the question).
2. Have clicks on that `iframe` call `focus` on the child window.
3. On `unload` of the child window, remove the `iframe`.

Just in case that other answer disappeared for any reason, here's the example in it:

HTML:

```
<input type='button' id='btnPopup' value='Click for Pop-Up'>
<p>This is text on the page</p>
<p>This is text on the page</p>
<p>This is text on the page</p>
<p>This is text on the page</p>
<p>This is text on the page</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#btnPopup').click(function() {
    $("<iframe id='shim' src='http://output.jsbin.com/abira4/1'>").css({
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      position: "absolute",
      left: "0px",
      top: "0px",
      zIndex: "100",
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      opacity: "0.5"
    }).appendTo(document.body);
    $("<div>Hi there, click me to dismiss</div>").css({
      zIndex: "101",
      border: "1px solid black",
      backgroundColor: "#ecc",
      position: "absolute",
      left: "100px",
      top: "100px"
    }).appendTo(document.body)
      .click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#shim").remove();
      });
  });
});
```

(`http://output.jsbin.com/abira4/1` is just a blank page.)

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ocobu4/1/) - Again, this is just #1 of the above, you'll need to add #2 and #3.

Comment: Thanks. Using iframe and its click events I am able to control my child window focus.