# How does the Chrome Web Store page work?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dialog, chrome-web-store

There are some oddities in the Chrome Web Store:

1. It opens dialogs navigating to new URLs
2. while this happens the screen doesn't flash
3. and the original page is still shown behind the dialog with the same items and scroll position

I have a background in HTML4 where I couldn't do this and I don't know if it is possible to do the same in HTML5.
My guess is that this behavior is because the Chrome browser has special behavior when handling its store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the new HTML5 `history.pushState();` method, as demoed [here](http://html5demos.com/history) and explained [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

Answer (score 1):

Read about [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/), [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/), etc.

Javascript is pretty powerful these days, and can be used to do some advanced stuff in your browser.  For diaglogs, you can look at things like [DOMWindow](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html), [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/), etc.  You can place an entirely separate web page into the pop-up dialog.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050174/what-is-the-best-alternative-for-jquery-thickbox) gathered some other suggestions too.  There are [many alternatives](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/).

Comment: Graham, I know how to create dialogs using these tools. My question is about how to change the url without flashing the screen.

Comment: Then I guess I didn't understand your question.  I don't see flashes.  From your question, it seems that you're seeing flashes when the Chrome Web Store opens dialogs?  Or did you miss a step in your explanation, and you're actually clicking on something inside the dialog to *visit* a new URL?

Comment: Browsers used to show a white page before loading a new webpage, but with rendering improvements they don't "flash" anymore. Flash is just an expression nowadays.